# Ошибка в Mercurial: abort: no username supplied

Tags: dvcs, mercurial, ubuntu

Только начал осваивать систему контроля версий, в частности `mercurial`. И вот такая проблема.
Когда я ввожу команду

```
hg commit
```

то получаю такую ошибку

```
abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")
```

Поиски в интернете привели к тому, что нужно создать файла `hgrc` в папке `.hg` проекта и ввести следующее:

```
[ui]
username = YourName
```

Но это не помогает. Что делать?

Comment: Должно помогать.

Comment: Я понимаю, что должно. Но почему-то не помогает. Я уже обыскался в поисках решения

Comment: А в файле точку перед hgrc поставить не забыли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте использовать «глобальный» файл конфигурации `~/.hgrc`